# Scrollbar inside a panel in the taskpane

Tags: vsto

I am trying to activate the scrollbar inside my panel which is bigger than my taskpane but the following code doesn't work...

> ```
>       Panel pane = new Panel();
>         pane.AutoScroll = true;
>         taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(pane, "try", inspector);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot add panel direct to the custom task pane. for that you have to create a user control in your application.

change the **AutoScroll** property of the user control to **true**
set the height of the user control. 
write the following code  in the `ThisAddIn.cs`:

```
        private UserControl1 myUserControl1;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            myUserControl1 = new UserControl1();
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane =
                this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane");
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
        }
```

Hope, this will work for you.

Comment: Are you sure I can set the autoscroll property for a usercontrol ? I can't find it.

Comment: if you a add a usercontrol via right click on project-> NewItem, choose usercontrol from options .  Then you will get a predefined usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

I mananaged to make it work by putting my usercontrol controls inside a

`<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></ScrollViewer>`